# Learning what DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is for

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I wonder which is what of the following:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'conf.settings'

os.environ[u'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = u'conf'
```

can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This defines the settings file name in case of production use.

In case of deployment you can use a separate settings file let us say *production_settings.py*  which imports from the main settings file *settings.py*. You could define some separate settings for deployment like `SITE_ID`, `DEBUG` etc.

So in your deployment .wsgi file `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable can be defined to use the separate settings file.

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'conf.production_settings'
```